# Use Java-function output in LaTeX

Tags: java, string, function, latex, output

Let's say, we have a Java-Function

```
public static String[] foo(int a, int b, int c){
    String[] retString = new String[3];
    retString[0] = "$n^2+x\\frac{o}{p}$";
    retString[1] = "bar $\\mathbb{Z}_{foobar}$";
    retString[2] = "value a is " + a + ", value b is " + b + ", value c is " + c;
    return retString;
}
```

Is there any possibility, to call this function inside my LaTeX code like `\foo{1}{2}{3}` and
use the returned String Array, as it would be normal LaTeX Code on multiple Lines in my LaTeX File?

Comment: Can't you just use a LaTeX macro?

Comment: I have written a bunch of such functions for my current project, my current workflow is to print them to console and copy and replace the outputs in my LaTeX Document, every time something changes. As you might assume, those functions are quite more complex as the example funtion, therefore it is not done with a simple \newcommand.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100852/include-java-code-to-display-text-in-latex